# Can I use and return EF4 code-first POCO entities as their interface?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, code-first, ef-code-first

Given the code later in the question, I am getting the following error from the EF4 code-first API:

> The given property 'Roles' is not a
>   supported navigation property.  The
>   property element type 'IRole' is
>   not a supported entity type. 
>   Interface types are not supported.

Basically, I have a Repository similar to the following:

```
public class Repository : IRepository {
    private IEntityProvider _provider;
    public Repository(IEntityProvider provider) {
        _provider = provider;
    }
    public IUser GetUser(int id) {
        return _provider.FindUser(id);
    }
}
```

Notice that the IRepository.GetUser returns an IUser.

Let's say my IEntityProvider implementation looks like this.

```
public class EntityProvider : IEntityProvider {
    public IUser FindUser(int id) {
        /* Using Entity Framework */
        IUser entity;
        using (var ctx = new MyDbContext()) {
            entity = (from n in ctx.Users 
                  where n.Id == id 
                  select (IUser)n).FirstOrDefault();
        }
        return entity;
    }
}
```

The key here is that the IUser interface has a List<IRole> property called Roles.  Because of this, it seems, the Entity Framework code-first cannot figure out what class to use to fulfill the IRole interface that property needs.

Below are the interfaces and POCO entities which would be used throughout the system and hopefully also used with EF4.

```
public interface IUser {
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    List<IRole> Roles { get; set; }
}

public interface IRole {
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public class User : IUser {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<IRole> Roles { get; set; }
}

public class Role : IRole {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Am I going about this the wrong way? Is there a way to do this within the EF4 code-first API?

I can only think of the following:

1. Some sort of shadow property (List<Role> DbRoles) that is used by EF4 code-first. Then use Data Annotations to make sure the actual List<IRole> is ignored by EF4.
2. Create duplicate classes for all entities which EF4 code-first will use and then Map those to the official ones that implement the interface.

Comment: Why do you want to use the interfaces instead?

Comment: That is definitely at the core of this question. Using interfaces allows flexibility, such as allowing revised entities to be able to implement the old interface, alternate implementations, downstream apps can work off the interface without knowledge of the domain entity, etc.  However, I am starting to think I shouldn't bother.

Comment: Flexibility is something to pay attention to, but you have to be realistic. Do you actually need it at the domain level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of Interfaces is not supported in EF 4 Code First (as of CTP5) and more than likely wont be supported in the RTM either. I would say make an abstract class in your DbContext to hold your objects.

Comment: ok, thanks, that is good information. Can you expand on the abstract class idea?  Are you recommending an abstract base class for each entity as an alternative to an interface?

Comment: IRepository <T> : where T : class (or something like RootEntity) T Find(Guid id), etc etc

Answer (score 2):

Remember, you need to make the base classes abstract, (check out inheritance with EF documents for that),
I recommend having a RootEntity with nothing in it, and then a Base entity with some common info, like Id, InsertedBy, UpdatedBy like standart fields, it makes everything much easier.